# C++ - CloseWindow with specifc exit code

Tags: c++, winapi, wndproc

Is there a way to close a window returning a specific code? I know PostQuitMessage() allows you to post the application's exit code, but everytime I call PostQuitMessage() in my thread the window hangs. I need to be able to exit my GUI with a specific code that will be given to the calling process.

I have a installer class that opens a window and waits for WndProc (same thread as the users answer depends on if the thread will continue executing or not) to send the WM_EXIT return value and depending on what the user picks (0 for successful install) (1 for user canceled or unsuccessful install) will determine what the application will do from there.

Here is some code to give you an idea, some syntax may be incorrect because I typed everything but the WndProc in StackOverFlow editor.

(Btw you may ask why you may force a download instead of letting the users decide, well what if a huge vulnerability was discovered that could for example be used maliciously so you patch it before you allow them the chance to find it, I got the idea from Microsoft because sometimes they require you to update)

```
int CreateUpdateWindow(){
    //MessageLoop function
    //Calls WndProc

   //return exit code
   return static_cast<int>(msg.wparam);
}
```

DLL Source (Trimmed):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch (uMsg) {

case WM_COMMAND:{

    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {

    case UpdateButton: {
        //User installs update
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    case CancelButton: {
        //User declines update
        PostQuitMessage(1);
        break;
    }


    }


    break;
}

case WM_DESTROY: {
    PostQuitMessage(1);
    break;
}


default: {
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

}


    return 0;
}
```

Main Window

```
 int main(){

  //Did the user cancel the install?
  //If he did exit the main process
 if (CreateUpdateWindow() == 1){
  ExitProcess(0);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need bind some data to window (say instance of class) and in this data you can save reason, why is Window closed. and use this data after window closed

Comment: Or if you're not worried about elegance, you could just use a global variable.

Comment: ... but it really isn't clear what you're asking here.  It sounds like you want to exit the application with a specific exit code that the parent process can read, but your comment to Remy's answer suggests otherwise.  Are you just trying to get the result back from the window procedure to main(), i.e., replace the code that says `return ... msg.wparam` with something that actually works?

Comment: (If so, is there some specific reason you're using a fully fledged window rather than a dialog box or message box?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I fixed my problem using a dialog box, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ExitProcess()` specifies the final exit code.  You are passing 0 when `CreateUpdateWindow()` returns 1.  You need to pass 1 instead:

```
//Did the user cancel the install?
//If he did exit the main process
if (CreateUpdateWindow() == 1){
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't what I needed, I need to get the exit code of WndProc (answer depends on what the user selects) then check what it is in "Main"  which is given by the return of "CreateUpdateWindow"

Comment: @TrevinCorkery then I'm completely lost what you are really asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using dialog boxes instead. I was creating a window to show update information but as Harry Johnston said, I should be using a dialog box for something like this.

It solved my problem in under a minute as you spawn your dialog with "DialogBox" and the return code is the value you give it in "EndDialog" (Inside of the dialog proc)

As shown:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (uMsg) {

    case WM_SHOWWINDOW: {

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDC_UPDATE: {
            EndDialog(hWnd, 1);
            break;
        }

        case IDC_CANCEL: {
            EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
            break;
        }
        }

        break;
    }


    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Function where I call the dialog and wait for the return value

```
int Adaptify::PromptInstall() {

    LoadLibrary(L"Riched20.dll");
    INT_PTR ReturnCode = DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, DlgProc);
    //ReturnCode is the value you gave it via EndDialog
    return 0;
}
```